# Sample Accord.NET Naive-Bayes

Tags: c#, .net, machine-learning, naivebayes, accord.net

I am new in `accord.net` and i am trying to apply step by step the following code from this [page](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/wiki/Classification) into a simple application of `Visual Studio C#`

The code of the section "Standard classification problems" has been applied with no problem but when i try to apply the code from section "Naive Bayes" during run-time i got an exception with that desciption

`unhandled exception of type System.AggregateException occurred in mscorlib.dll` 
With no further desciption.

This happens in the following command

`var nb = learner.Learn(inputs, outputs)`

My code is the following

```
DataTable table = new celReader("examples.xls").GetWorksheet("Classification - Yin Yang");
 // Convert the DataTable to input and output vectors
 double[][] inputs = table.ToArray<double>("X", "Y");
 int[] outputs = table.Columns["G"].ToArray<int>();

 // Plot the data
 ScatterplotBox.Show("Yin-Yang", inputs, outputs).Hold();

 var learner = new NaiveBayesLearning<NormalDistribution>();
 // Estimate the Naive Bayes
 var nb = learner.Learn(inputs, outputs); // this is where exception is thrown

 // Classify the samples using the model
 int[] answers = nb.Decide(inputs);

 // Plot the results
 ScatterplotBox.Show("Expected results", inputs, outputs);
 ScatterplotBox.Show("Naive Bayes results", inputs, answers).Hold();
```

The stacktrace of my program

[image]

Comment: Can you post stacktrace of the exception ? Have checked in debug which line breaks?

Comment: @tchrikch updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **examples.xls** downloaded from the same page you indicated in your post seems to have bad/incompatible/outdated data. In column **G**, replacing all **-1** with **0** (rows 2 to 51) does the trick, using **Accord v3.4.2-alpha**.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer. But do have any idea why do i have do your suggested change in .xls ?

Comment: My understanding is that the **G** column (G for group) is just a _convention_ establishing if a particular point belongs to one group or another (Yin or Yang). At some point in time this convention may have been changed in the source code but not in the data from the **xls**. If you download the source code from their samples you get the correct **xls**, and that's how i found out about it.

Comment: No it does no work the way you told me...Maybe it has something t do about the version of accord? Because i have installed the 3.4.0 and i cant find the version you mentioned

Comment: Right-click your project, select **Manage Nuget Packages**, go to **Installed** tab on your left and finally select the version you want to your right and click the **Update** button. Make sure all Accord packages have a green check marker after that, otherwise repeat this operation for each sub-package.

Comment: I have already checked for updates in nuget package manager. I am pretty sure that the last version of accord is the 3.4.0 according to visual studio